# Integration of Hypergeometric 2F1 on the real axis with arbitrary extrema of integrations

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function

I have to compute the integral

$$
\int_x^1 dz \,  z^\alpha (1-z)^\beta \;  _2F_1(a_1,a_2;b_1;z)
$$
where $x$ is some positive real number $0 \le x<1$. If $x=0$ then the answer is a $_3F_2$ (see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric3F2/07/01/01/)), but I don't know how to solve this for general $x$, and Mathematica gives no answer. Does anybody know if there is any closed form for this integral?

If that helps, what I'm interested is the case $a_1=a_2=b_1/2>0$, but general $\alpha$ and $\beta$ (real numbers such that the integral converges).

Comment: I suggest to consider the undefined integral: http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/21/01/02/02/. To consider a more general one, you have to define the H-Fox-Function of two variables: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266566090_The_H-function_Theory_and_Applications

Comment: thanks! the first link treats cases too specific for me. Would you be able to point me to the relevant section of the second link? Reading the TOC and skimming through it gave no result

Comment: You are looking for the general Euler transform of the hypergeometric function. For this several generalizations are made. If you consider the definite integral from 0 to 1 you get the H-Fox function - Meijer G of one variable- or general hypergemetric function. In your case - the undefined integral - you use the H-Fox function of two variables -> page 207. For the case of a fixed x you get the formula  (2.53). Meijer G of two variables you have to search. Kampe Ferriet https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01112721. I have the H-Fox for Mathematica for one variable.

Comment: If you need an algorithm to calculate the Euler transform please let me know.